# How to generate create table script without primary and foreign key in Oracle

Tags: oracle, ddl, table, scripting

I have lots of schemas and tables. I want to generate create script of all of my tables. I am using below statement and it is working pretty well.

```
SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('TABLE','table_name','schema') FROM DUAL
```

But this statement also generates all primary and foreign key scripts that belong to table. So, is there any way to not include primary and foreign keys in create table scripts

Comment: Why don't you want at least primary keys?!

Comment: I don't want primary keys. I want table script without primary keys because I have too many tables and it causes problems when inserting these tables to another location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
set pagesize 0
set long 90000 

exec DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM,'STORAGE',false);
exec DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'CONSTRAINTS',false);
exec DBMS_METADATA.SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM(DBMS_METADATA.SESSION_TRANSFORM, 'REF_CONSTRAINTS',false);

SELECT DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL( 'TABLE','table_name','schema') FROM DUAL;
```

This should result in the DDL without any indexes and foreign keys.

Reference:

- [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_metada.htm#i1000135)
- [dba-oracle.com](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_1_dbms_metadata.htm)

Comment: When I paste and copy above to TOAD it gave ORA-00900. But I changed your statement by adding "execute" statement to each proc, then it worked. Thanks

Comment: But I really don't understand why it did not work as your statement. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @osman they made an error, it doesn't work in query mode in sqldeveloper or in sqlplus. i've fixed the error, waiting on edit to be approved.

Comment: @booyaa I run this "SELECT * FROM ALL_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'  and object_name = 'SET_TRANSFORM_PARAM'" but got zero. I think I could find one?

Comment: sorry for the typo. Was on the run to a meeting. Yes, @booyaa is right. EXEC for each line is correct.